# how to keep apostrophe when processing text in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I defined a function to preprocess text like this,

```
import re

def prep_text(sen):

    sen = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', sen)
    sen = re.sub(r"\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+", ' ', sen)
    sen = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', sen)  
    sen = sen.lower()
    return sen    

print(prep_text("I can't HANDLE this"))
```

This gives the result;

```
 i can handle this
```

Hence missing the meaning. How can i keep apostrophe when i preprocess the data?

I want the output like this;

```
i can't handle this
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to keep "can't " as it is..

Comment: Of course you lose the aposthrophies, since you are explicitly removing them with the first `re.sub`...

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, if you "want to keep can't as it is" don't do anything to the string. I repeat, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has solved my problem. I should have avoided `sen = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', sen)`;

```
import re

def prep_text(sen):

    sen = sen.split()
    sen = ' '.join(sen)

    #sen = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', sen) # i should have avoided this

    sen = re.sub(r"\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+", ' ', sen) # to remove if any single char

    sen = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', sen) # to remove if any multiple spaces

    sen = sen.lower()

    return sen

print(prep_text("I can't HANDLE this"))
```

> > i can't handle this